# Problema em criar uma função de login em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estou trabalhando em um teste simulação de uma espécie de loja porém as funções iniciais que estou trabalhando são de cadastro e de login.

Aqui está minha função de cadastro:

```
def cadastro():
    print("Olá, usuário! Seja bem vindo! Aqui é a sua área de Cadastro!")
    time.sleep(1.85)
    nome: str = input("Insira seu nome: ")
    sobrenome: str = input("Insira seu sobrenome: ")
    email: str = input("Insira seu email: ")
    senha: str = input("Insira sua senha: ")
    confirmar_senha: str = input("Insira sua senha novamente: ")
    if senha == confirmar_senha:
        print(f'Obrigado por ter feito o cadastro, {nome} {sobrenome}! Tenha um ótimo dia!')
    else:
        print("Tente novamente")

    with open('lista_de_usuarios.csv', 'a') as arquivo:
        escritor = writer(arquivo)
        escritor.writerow([nome + ' ' + sobrenome, email, senha])
```

Ela tá funcionando normal e eu já testei isso
O problema está na função de login:

```
def login():
    em = input("Insira seu email: ")
    se = input("Insira sua senha: ")
    with open('lista_de_usuarios.csv', 'r') as ar:
        read = reader(ar, delimiter=' ')
        if (em in read) and (se in read) is True:
            print(f"Login realizado com sucesso! Bem vindo, {em} {se}!")
            return True
        else:
            print("Tente novamente! Se você não fez o cadastro, volte a tela de cadastro e faça o mesmo!")
```

Independente se o meu input está exatamente igual ao do arquivo, ele sempre retorna False

Porque acontece isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O principal problema é que `csv.reader` retorna um *iterator*, que é um objeto semelhante a uma lista ou tupla, porém que não guarda todas as informações na memória quando é construído. Isso significa que o seu único propósito é, como sugere o nome, iterar sobre ele.

Nesse caso, você deveria iterar sobre cada entrada da sua tabela para verificar se existe algum usuário com aquele e-mail cadastrado e depois ver se a senha associada àquele e-mail bate com a senha fornecida. Você está cometendo um erro de lógica na sua autenticação no trecho

```
if (em in read) and (se in read) is True:
    print(f"Login realizado com sucesso! Bem vindo, {em} {se}!")
```

Isso vai permitir que o usuário autentique se existir alguma senha que seja igual à que ele digitou, o que não quer dizer que é a senha dele. Não tive tempo para testar se funciona ou não, mas experimente o código abaixo:

```
read = reader(ar, delimiter=' ')

for user in read:
    if user[1] == em and user[2] == se:
        print('login autorizado')

else:
    print('usuário não cadastrado em nossa base de dados')
```

Estou assumindo aqui que o e-mail e a senha sejam a segunda e a terceira informação dentro de cada linha de sua tabela, como deu para entender do exemplo que mostraste. Aí, nesse caso, `user[1]` e `user[2]` representam cada e-mail e cada senha dos usuários cadastrados na tabela.

Talvez o `for`/`else` seja novidade para você. Basicamente, se o laço `for` encerrou "normalmente" (sem `break`), ele vai executar o `else` subsequente. Nessa situação, caso nenhuma linha com credenciais compatíveis tenha sido encontrado, então o usuário não existe.

Comment: Mano, pior que a lógica está correta e eu fico agradecido por isso. Porém o maior problema do arquivo csv é que ele não aceita os valores integrados dentro da lista como variaveis separadas e por causa disso, ela dá IndexError. Conhece uma outra extensão de arquivo que posso trabalhar com isso?

Comment: CSV não serve para criar um banco de dados; infelizmente, também sou inexperiente e não mexi com bancos ainda. O problema ao qual você está se referindo é causado porque, ao escrever, você está usando o delimitador padrão do `csv.writer`, que eu não sei qual é, mas deve ser a vírgula simples. Agora, na hora de ler, você está especificando que `delimiter=' '`. Deve ser por causa disso que ele não está interpretando direito.

Comment: Tudo bem. Obrigado pela ajuda!